# While loop timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pause my code if it has taken less time to run than 1 minute. (then continue to run the rest of the code after that minute has passed). However it only waits for around 30 seconds, so it seems to be timing out. Is this the general behaviour?

I currently have this:

```
 minumum_code_run_time = Time.zone.now + 1.minute
 
 # run code
 
 while Time.zone.now < minimum_code_run_time
 end

# carry on with rest of code
```

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please elaborate on why you are doing that? And in what context, for example, back ground job vs. model or controller? What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a controller? If so, you should look at using a job queue instead.

Comment: Are you sure that actually the while loop times out? Or could it be the web server that is timing out? For example, [Heroku times out all requests after 30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) per default.

Comment: Are you aware, that Ruby has [`Timeout`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) in its standard library? There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Instead of running a loop at 100% cpu usage, you can just `sleep(60)`. However, doing so will still consume resources and might block other systems like your web server (which is likely the cause for the 30s time out). Why do you want to artificially extend your code's run time in the first place?